# C++ how to call a method from a class chosen by user input

Tags: c++, oop, input

So i have an assignment and im evaluating this as a "maybe its a solution", but i dont know if this is possible so you tell me...

Lets say we have this class

```
class Person
{
  private:
  string name;
  int number;
  public:
  Person(string n, int num)
  {
    name = n;
    number = num;
  }
  void greeting()
  {
    std::cout<<"hello my name is"<<this->name<< "and my number is"<<this->number;
  }
}
```

And we have multiple persons in the main, and i want the user to input the name of a person and then the person with that name to call its greeting method.

Like this: (its just an idea to frame the question better, it obviously wont compile)

```
int main(){
//assume lots of person objects are already declared, and the inuput name corresponds to an existent person and so on... 
Person person;
std::cin>>person;
person.greeting();
}
```

¿so is that idea in c++ possible?

note: this is not my actual assingment, its just a simplificated way to illustrate my question.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you tried putting the `Person`s in a container, then iterating over the container to find the correct one?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. The shown code would need an `operator >>` for extracting `Person` objects from a `std::istream&`, and if you're collecting these in some container, a chosen way of keying or enumerating that container.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a map, your constructor was wrong too

```
class Person
{
private:
    string name;
    int number;
public:
    Person(string n, int num)
    {
        name  = n;
        number = num;
    }
    void greeting()
    {
        std::cout << "hello my name is" << this->name << "and my number is" << this->number;
    }
};
int main() {
    string person;
    std::map<string, Person> people;
    people.emplace(std::make_pair("Anne", Person("Anne", 42)));
    people.emplace(std::make_pair("Dave", Person("Dave", 42)));
    std::cin >> person;
    auto look = people.find(person);
    if (look != people.end()) { // did we find them?
        look->second.greeting();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a hash table map. Or more precisely, `std::unordered_map`

```
int main()
{
    Person *selbie = new Person("selbie", 8675309);
    Person *tomas = new Person("Tomas", 4441212);
    Person *joe= new Person("Joe", 3218890);

    std::unordered_map<string, Person*> peopleMap;

    peopleMap["selbie"] = selbie;
    peopleMap["tomas"] = tomas;
    peopleMap["joe"] = joe;

    
    std::string name;
    std::cin >> name;

    auto itor = peopleMap.find(name);
    if (itor != peopleMap.end())
    {
        People* personOfInterest = itor->second;
        personOfInterest->greeting();
    }

    // don't forget to cleanup all your objects when done
    delete selbie;
    delete tomas;
    delete joe;

}
```

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating the `Person`s? You could simply take the address of the stack objects to make the same map in this case. Or even better, store the objects in the map instead of pointers. Do not push inexperienced programmers into bad habits with bad examples.

Comment: @Mestkon - because in the real world, you rarely have you entire database operating for the lifetime of a single function call.  Or more precisely, I didn't want the OP to think it was safe to store pointers to stack items in a map.